# Getting sum of 2 columns each with unique condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I've two tables like this.

```
create table teams (
  "ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "STADIUM_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "NAME" Varchar2 (50) NOT NULL ,
    primary key ("ID") 
    ) ;

create table matches (
  "ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "WINNER_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "OPPONENT_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "WINNERSCORE" Integer,
  "OPPONENTSCORE" Integer,
primary key ("ID","WINNER_ID","OPPONENT_ID") 
) ;
```

They have the following data :

```
select * from matches;

    ID      WINNER_ID OPPONENT_ID WINNERSCORE OPPONENTSCORE
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -------------
     1          5           2           5             2
     2          4           5           1             0
     3          3           2           1             0
     4          3           2           1             0
     5          1           2           2             0
     6          3           1           2             1

select * from teams;

    ID     STADIUM_ID    NAME
---------- ---------- -----------
     1          1        Team1
     2          3        Team2
     3          4        Team3
     4          2        Team4
     5          5        Team5
```

I need to get the sum of the goals for each team.
For this aim, tried the following query and got the results below :

```
select name,
       (select sum(opponentscore)
          from matches
         where opponent_id = teams.id) +
       (select sum(winnerscore) from matches where winner_id = teams.id) sum
  from teams;

NAME                                                      SUM
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Team1                                                       3
Team2
Team3
Team4
Team5                                                       5
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to calculate seperately *opponentscore* and *winnerscore* by each individual team, and combine them with *UNION ALL* :

```
select name, sum(score) total_score 
  from
(
 select name, sum(winnerscore) score
   from teams t join matches m on ( t.id = m.winner_id  )
  group by name
 union all
 select name, sum(opponentscore) score
   from teams t join matches m on ( t.id = m.opponent_id  )
  group by name
)
group by name
order by 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb618f/6)

Answer (score 0):

you should use join and group by

```
  select name, sum(matches.opponentscore) + sum(matches.winnerscore) my_sum
  from matches 
  inner join teams on teams.id = matches.winner_id 
  group by  teams.name
```

Comment: The OP sums `opponentscore` where the team is "opponent" and `winnerscore` where the team is "winner". Your query counts both on the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could join table teams twice with table matches:

`SELECT name, SUM(wonMatches.WINNERSCORE + lostMatches.OPPONENTSCORE) as goals
 FROM (teams INNER JOIN matches as wonMatches ON teams.ID = wonMatches.WINNER_ID)
      INNER JOIN matches as lostMatches ON teams.ID = lostMatches.OPPONENT_ID
 GROUP BY name`

Comment: Are u sure the syntax is correct? I'm getting missing keyword error

Comment: guess it's something after the second oppening bracket, but i cant figure out how to fix this

Comment: Might need an alias for the derived table (just before inner join)?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is : change your database schema. Restart thinking your app's requirements. This schema does not answer the value your user are expecting from you.

From what I see, I would say that you're trying to build an app for fans that want to track their team / favorite player progress so they can brag.

That being said, I would have, at the end, those tables :

- fan
- team (id_team)
- player (id_player, id_team)
- tournament (id_tournament)
- match (id_match, id_tournament, start_on, id_team_home, id_team_visitor)
- goals (id_match, id_player, goaled_on)

So now, I believe that writing your query would be much more simple. You'll just have to join team, player, count over goals and group by team.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `NULL`s - the subqueries return `NULL` when no result is found, and `NULL + anything == NULL`.

Most straightforward fix is:

```
select name,
       nvl(
           (select sum(opponentscore) from matches where opponent_id = teams.id),
           0
       )
       +
       nvl(
           (select sum(winnerscore) from matches where winner_id = teams.id),
           0
       ) sum
from teams;
```

For performance reasons tohugh, you might want to consider using a joined query with GROUP BY as suggested by others.